# How to get a shell command to work in php with exec

Tags: php, macos, shell, imagemagick

When I run in a terminal:

```
convert file.pdf file.png
```

everything works fine, but when I do this in a php script as:

```
exec('convert file.pdf file.png');
```

I get errors. When I search online how to solve these errors I end up making subtle changes to files here, and permissions there. The errors change and I have no idea how I got to where I am. I feel as though I am chasing a phantom.

I don't know whether the problem lies with imagemagick, php, ghostscript, permissions, etc.

So my question is: How should I go about so that I can re-attack this problem from the beginning? Do I need to reinstall things? If so, what and on what order? What should have what permissions?

I appreciate that my question is rather open, but judging by the multitude of similar questions, with all sorts of different answers, it would be good to have some clear definite checklist to work through.

For completeness I am using mac osx, Yosemite; php 5.5.27;  ImageMagick 6.9.1-10; gs 9.16 and the present error says:

```
convert: no images defined `file.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
```

I am also using full path names for the convert and the files too.

With 'shell_exec' I get more error messages:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib 
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gs  
Reason: Incompatible library version: gs requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0

convert: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE - dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300"  "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-9254642RiQMO2CuWM%d" "-f/var/tmp/magick-92546j8PosqIIrra3" "-f/var/tmp/magick-92546LB13giWos7rr"' (-1) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/483.

convert: no images defined `file.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
```

Comment: Is that the complete error message? If not, can you add all of it?

Comment: @thatotherguy I've edited it in.

Comment: Is that all of it now? There are no preceding lines like e.g.  `convert.im6: unable to open image \`file.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.`?

Comment: @Geoff: In terminal what is the output of `which gs`?

Comment: @thatotherguy That's the only error message I get when I 'echo'. Oh, hang on: with `exec` I get just that message: with shell_exec I get more. I'll update in the question.

Comment: @l'L'l 'which gs' returns '/usr/local/bin/gs'

Comment: @Geoff: How did you install `ImageMagick` and `GhostScript`, (eg. macports, homebrew, compiled source)?

Comment: @l'L'l I used homebrew. I have already uninstalled both and reinstalled them.

Comment: The last error you show is referring to an outdated `libtiff` library, so maybe try updating that and/or update/reinstall `imagemagick` (latest is 6.9.2-3). If you reinstalled it's odd that you wouldn't have the latest... maybe homebrew is behind though. I always use `macports`, so can't really say much as to what `homebrew` is doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91032/discussion-between-geoff-and-lll).

Answer (score 0):

Note that PHP's `shell_exec` takes a string argument:

```
shell_exec('convert file.pdf file.png');
```